# How to get the balance for a specific account using py-substrate

Tags: python, substrateinterface

The following code will return the balance for a few random accounts?  How would I pass in a specific account that I am interested in?

```
url = 'wss://karura.polkawallet.io'
substrate = SubstrateInterface(url)
hash = substrate.get_chain_finalised_head()
result = substrate.query_map('System', 'Account', block_hash = hash, max_results=2)
for account, account_info in result:
     print(f"Free balance of account '{account.value}': {account_info.value['data']['free']}")
```

The [docs](https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-interface/#substrateinterface.SubstrateInterface.query) mention that you can pass a list in the params argument, but I tried various ways to pass in a list and I can't get it to work.  Here is one way I tried:

```
result = substrate.query_map('System', 'Account', params = ["account=qhYSTHXnF19w3ahxdyxWbrz4kuRm5R5S61RbzFed5LATc86"], block_hash = hash, max_results=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `query_map` function queries multiple entries of a map.
If you just want a single value, you can use `query` instead.
Try the following on a local Substrate or Polkadot development node to see how it works:

```python
from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface


# Connect to a local `polkadot --dev` or `substrate --dev` node.
url = 'ws://127.0.0.1:9944'
substrate = SubstrateInterface(url)

# Alice' development address from https://docs.substrate.io/v3/tools/subkey/#well-known-keys
address = '5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY'

block = substrate.get_chain_finalised_head()
result = substrate.query('System', 'Account', params = [address], block_hash = block)
free = result.value['data']['free']

print(f'Account {address} has {free} planks free balance')
```

Output:

```
Account 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY has 1000000000000000000000 planks free balance
```